Syntax to minimize function of a vector?
I have a linear function of 2 vectors, C1 and C2, that reproduces a rate, and I want to minimize the $\chi^2$ using observation data and uncertainties saved in variable S. Length of vectors C1 and C2 is the same as Ca and Cb, that is 260. Do I have to manually type in all the 520 variables in the Minimize function or there is a smarter way?
Note added: this is just an example, I know the answer in this case is trivial, I just need the syntax to use it in a real-world scenario. I will need to numerically minimise the function because I will need to require that the coefficients are all smaller than something, I cannot use LinearSolve.
Ca = Table[RandomReal[],{i,1,260}];
Cb = Table[RandomReal[],{i,1,260}];
S = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 10}];
Rate[C1_, C2_] := Ca . C1 + Cb . C2;
Chi2[C1_, C2_] := Sum[(S[[i, 1]] - Rate[C1, C2])^2/S[[i, 2]]^2, {i, 1, Length[S]}];


See also examples in document of NMinimize:  https://i.sstatic.net/EDq1S7cZ.png

In this case, I think it makes more sense to join Ca and Cb together into a 1x520 matrix like this
